# How to populate a DropDown in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to get the id and Name about Costumers to DropDown in Laravel5 , in Laravel4 I use the following code.

```
public function create()
    {
        $data = ['groups' => Cliente::lists('name', 'id')];
        return view('projects.create')->with('data',$data);
    }
```

After , In the View I show with the following

```
{{ Form::select('group', $groups) }}
```

But in the controller Client I have this

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
 class ClienteController extends Controller {


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Cliente::all();
        return $projects;
        }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */


}
```

When I execute the view create , I can see the following error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cliente' not found
```

---

Finally I use this but I need to show the name and id about client in the view not only the id, any solutions for this ?

```
public function create()
    {
    $data = ['Selecciona el ID del ususario' => \DB::table('clientes')->lists('id','id')];
    return view('projects.create')->with('groups',$data);
```

Then , the view.

{!!Form::select('user_id', $groups) !!}

Comment: You have to specify the namespace of Cliente. This is normally App. So put above you're class ```use App\Cliente;```

Comment: Thanks , it's a stupid fail but I have another doubt (the question was update)

Comment: Why is ```->lists('id','name')``` not working?

Comment: This work correctly but I only can see one term in the form , I need show the ID+Name about client.